# REST Console for Chrome - How can I get request execution time?

Tags: google-chrome, rest

Can somebody guide me how to get request execution time on REST Console for Chrome?
I wanted to estimate some of the REST API execution time while testing it through REST Console.

Comment: Are you interested in the time the client sees or in the actual time it takes to execute the request on the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [network tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview) in chrome..

Comment: I'm going to be extremely literal here and say that all that gives you is the time it takes between the client sending the request and receiving the response. So this actually measures network latency plus transmission time + server-side execution time. Network latency can be quite a large part of the total time it takes for the client to receive an answer.

It may be that's what the OP wants. It may not.

Comment: Yes, I agree but if he is looking from chrome then he can only get time with network latency  + transmission time + server side execution time. Only nileshgm can put some light on it wht exactly he wants :)

Answer (score 0):

this will be a feature added into the new version of REST Console, feel free to open a ticke to track the progress: https://github.com/codeinchaos/restconsole/issues